# Automatic link of commit to User Story not working with #ID

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a git repo in Azure DevOps Repos, I also have a test User Story set up.

I cloned the master branch and opened it in VSCode and then on commit I used the extension to select my User Story automatically which added #ID to the commit message and then pushed the change back to the master branch.

When I then look at my User Story in DevOps there is no linked check-in.

Am I missing some kind of linkage, my VSCode is connected to my DevOps and it was able to list the User Story in VSCode when I used the add work items option no problem so not sure what the issue is. Assuming this isn't a one way thing where I have to create a branch from the user story and link it at that point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Automatic link of commit to User Story not working with #ID

Please check if the repository option **Submit mention link** is enabled:

Go to `Project Settings`->`Repositories`:

[image]

This option will allow you to **automatically create links for work items mentioned in a commit comment**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome thank you that did the job, having just done a google for "azure repos commit mention linking" it still didn't pull up a decent article about this setting :-(

Answer (score 1):

For some reason (that I have yet to figure out) this setting was not on in about half our repositories). 
I have enabled this now for all repositories (one-by-one as there is no general setting for this, unless somebody knows how).

Also is there an option to generate the links for existing commits that where done before enabling this setting?